# I have been trying to build tensorflow with GPU support for about a week now and keep running into installation issues

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, bazel, cudnn

I have been trying to build tensorflow with GPU support for about a week now and keep running into installation issues with bazel.  Granted, I am able to run my GPU outside of this process.  Windows 10 machine , cuda 8.0, cudnn 5.1

I believe it has something to do with my environment variables not pointing to the right path and/or a path that is referenced in a file somewhere that is pointing to the usr/local/bin folder as opposed to the C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0

If someone can provide the correct paths that would be extremely helpful.  Another thought was whether I needed to modify bazel configure files to help with this issue?   [Environment paths here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITotA.jpg)

My error:

> C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpu\tensorflow>bazel build -c opt --copt=mavx tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain
>   .
>   ERROR: error loading package 'tensorflow/examples/image_retraining': Encountered error while reading extension file 'cuda/build_defs.bzl': no such package '@local_config_cuda//cuda': Traceback (most recent call last):
>           File "C:/users/me/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 915
>                   _create_cuda_repository(repository_ctx)
>           File "C:/users/me/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 803, in _create_cuda_repository
>                   _get_cuda_config(repository_ctx)
>           File "C:/users/me/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 619, in _get_cuda_config
>                   _cudnn_install_basedir(repository_ctx)
>           File "C:/users/me/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 202, in _cudnn_install_basedir
>                   auto_configure_fail("Cannot find cudnn install path....)
>           File "C:/users/me/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 125, in auto_configure_fail
>                   fail("
>   %sAuto-Configuration Error:%s ...))
>
> Auto-Configuration Error: Cannot find cudnn install path.
>   .
>   INFO: Elapsed time: 21.262s

Answer (score 1):

I did solve this problem.   The answer lies in the forward slashes and backslashes between the windows environment and presumably the linux environment.

I made sure to include the forward slashes in the cuda_configure.bzl

`_DEFAULT_CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH = "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v8.0"
_DEFAULT_CUDNN_INSTALL_PATH = "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v8.0"`

as well as the environment variables in windows.

Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `CUDNN_INSTALL_PATH` environment variable:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/da0d883cba8c3b8103e17432bf8398a56a719c40/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl#L16

Comment: I tried setting the path to `DEFAULT_CUDNN_INSTALL_PATH = "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v8.0/bin`    and `DEFAULT_CUDNN_INSTALL_PATH = "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v8.0/lib/x64` as well as just the root  8.0 directory and none of those seemed to help.